# Render a list of React components with additional text

Tags: reactjs

I wish to remember an array of checkboxes. This is possible, however, I would like to have text next to the checkbox to describe the option.

```
options = ["option 1", "option 2", "option 3"];
options = options.map((option) => <Checkbox value={option} key={option}/>);

  return (
    <CheckboxGroup name={name} onChange={onChange}>
      {options}
    </CheckboxGroup>
  );
```

this will render:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="option 1">
<input type="checkbox" value="option 2">
<input type="checkbox" value="option 3">
```

However, I would like to be able to render this:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="option 1">option 1
<input type="checkbox" value="option 2">option 2
<input type="checkbox" value="option 3">option 3
```

What would be the best way to render this group of options with the option name next to the component?

Comment: Are you using a 3rd party control to render checkboxes?

Comment: yes I am, it is here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-checkbox-group

Comment: You can just render them as `(option) => (<label><Checkbox  value={option} key={option}/> option</label>)`

Answer (score 0):

Input elements do not have any children. You'll have to wrap your checkbox in a `p` or `div` with associated text. Then you can format it how you'd like it to appear

Something like `<div><input.../>{option}</div>` should do it

Answer (score 0):

Based on OP's comment and the 3rd party component's docs, you can get them by doing:

```
options = options.map((option) => (<label><Checkbox value={option} key={option}/>{option}</label>));
```

Wrapping them in `label` accomplishes 2 things:

- it makes the HTML semantically correct (anyone clicking on label text will check the checkbox automatically; tabbing focus will work and so on)
- React expects you to wrap things in single wrapper (can be a span or div but only label gives you the above semantic benefits).

Answer (score 0):

```
render() {
    options = ["option 1", "option 2", "option 3"];
    options = options.map((option) => <label><Checkbox value={option} key={option}/> {option} </label>);

    return (
      <CheckboxGroup name="fruits">
        {options}
      </CheckboxGroup>
    );
  }
```